# Using memcpy for two dimensional dynamic array?

Tags: c, memcpy

I am able to declare in a good way two matrices A and B.

But, when using the memcpy (to copy B from A), B gives me arrays of 0s.

How can I do? Is my code correct for using memcpy?

```
int r = 10, c = 10, i, j;

int (*MatrixA)[r];
MatrixA=malloc(c * sizeof(*MatrixA));
int (*MatrixB)[r];
MatrixB=malloc(c * sizeof(*MatrixB));

memcpy(MatrixB,MatrixA,c * sizeof(MatrixA));


for(i=1;i<r+1;i++)
{
     for (j = 1; j < c+1; j++)
    {
        MatrixA[i][j]=j;
         printf("A[%d][%d]= %d\t",i,j,MatrixA[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");printf("\n");printf("\n");printf("\n");printf("\n");

for(i=1;i<r+1;i++)
{
     for (j = 1; j < c+1; j++)
    {
        printf("B[%d][%d]= %d\t",i,j,MatrixB[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Well, have you initialized the `malloc`ated space at all?

Comment: `memcpy(MatrixB,MatrixA,c * sizeof(MatrixA));` --> `memcpy(MatrixB,MatrixA,c * sizeof(*MatrixA));` and move to after value  set to `MatrixA`. also index is out of bounds. because 0 origin.

Comment: I think it' s not a fact of malloc because the A matrix is well declared and the output is well printed.

Comment: Yes but you initialize `MatrixA` after copying its (undefined) contents to `MatrixB`. Also, indices start at `0`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean by move to after value set to MatrixA? Can you give me further details? I have changed the memcpy instruction with what you have provided but it still gives 0 for values of B.

Comment: see [SAMPLE](http://ideone.com/w2q05k)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY In your SAMPLE code, shouldn't `for(i = 0; i < r; i++) { for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {` --> `for(i = 0; i < c; i++) { for (j = 0; j < r; j++) {`?

Comment: @CoolGuy I was changed to `int (*MatrixA)[c];MatrixA=malloc(r * sizeof(*MatrixA));` in order to adapt to the for-loop. It needs to match.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh. I did not see that you changed that.

Answer (score 3):

You copied contents before initializing `MatrixA` .And also you access index out of bound (`r+1` evaluates `11` which is out of bound) causing *UB*. Do this instead -

```
for(i=0;i<r;i++)            //  i starts from 0 
{
    for (j =0; j < c; j++)         // j from 0
  {
       MatrixA[i][j]=j;
       printf("A[%d][%d]= %d\t",i,j,MatrixA[i][j]);
  }
   printf("\n");
}

memcpy(MatrixB,MatrixA,c * sizeof(*MatrixA));   // copy after setting MatrixA

for(i=0;i<r;i++)              // similarly indexing starts with 0
{
    for (j =0; j < c; j++)
  {
    printf("B[%d][%d]= %d\t",i,j,MatrixB[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is my code correct for using memcpy?

No, your code is wrong, but that's less of a `memcpy` problem. You're simply doing C arrays wrong.

```
int r = 10, c = 10, i, j;

int (*MatrixA)[r];
MatrixA=malloc(c * sizeof(*MatrixA));
```

Ok, `MatrixA` is now a pointer to a 10-element array of integers right? So the compiler reserves memory for ten ints; however, in the `malloc` line, you overwrite that with a pointer to a memory region of ten times the size of a single integer. A code analysis tool will tell you that you've built a memory leak.

These mistakes continue throughout your code; you will have to understand the difference between statically allocated C arrays and dynamic allocation using `malloc`.

Comment: No , I don't think so .There _is_ need to allocate memory to it  because `MatrixA` is just a pointer and uninitialized.

Comment: @Marcus Muller, I would like to use the memcpy with dynamic arrays as my code listed above. Can you give me at least what is the right instruction to write with memcpy?

Comment: You're doing dynamic arrays wrong, so no, I won't help you shoot your own foot.

Comment: @ameyCU: you're right regarding the uninitializedness, but it's already allocated, so malloc is wrong here, definitely.

Comment: "*`MatrixA` is now a 10-element array of int pointers, right?*" No. You are thinking of `int *MatrixA[r];`. `int (*MatrixA)[r];` is a pointer to an array of `r` ints.

Comment: malloc doesn't initialize, but, as the name suggests, *allocates* memory

Comment: "*the compiler reserves memory for ten ints;*" - Huh?